# how to access value object from returned service in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a service which returns an actual data. but when I call it in the controller, the return data structure is a bit confusing.

here is my factory:

```js
app.factory("studentService", ['$http','$q','$localstorage','$state', 
    function($http,$q,$localstorage,$state) {

 return{
      getStudentsFrom : function(index){
                 return $http.get(app.baseUrlServer + app.getStudentsUrl + '/getbasedonindex/'+index)
                    .then(function(response){
                        if (response.data) {
                            return response.data;
                        } else {
                            // invalid response
                            return $q.reject(response.data);
                        }
                    },function(response){
                        // invalid response
                        return $q.reject(response.data);
                    });
            }
 }

}]);
```

Here is my controller that calls it

```js
var app_ctrl = angular.module('app.controllers');

app_ctrl.controller('BrowseController',['$scope','$state', 'studentService', '$localstorage', 
 function($scope,$state, studentService, $localstorage, $timeout) {
  
   $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false;
 // $scope.NumOfRows=studentService.getNumOfRows();

  $scope.students = [];
  $scope.counter=1;

console.log(studentService.getStudentsFrom($scope.counter));

  

}]);
```

and here is what I get.

```js
Promise {$$state: Object, then: function, catch: function, finally: function}
$$state: Object
status: 1
value: Array[1]
0: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

The question is, how can I access the value?, thanks

Answer (score 4):

The function $http.get return a promise you need to use it on this way :

```
studentService.getStudentsFrom($scope.counter).then(
    function(result) {
       console.log(result);
    }
);
```

see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
or
 https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: I've done that, but I need to access the result outside of the then() block. I've tried to pass it to array, but it fails populating the array variable when I try to access it outside of the then() block

Comment: Olivier is correct. Taking this a step further you will realize that your service code is superfluous.

Comment: `studentService.getStudentsFrom($scope.counter).then(
    function(result) {
       $scope.students = result;
    }
);` 

Not working?

Comment: unfortunately it's not working, u can try it Oliver : ). 
it is works when you console.log() inside of the then () block. but outside.. your $scope.students remains empty, and it executes first

Comment: @BilalBayasut the problem is you are still thinking the problem as traditional blocking code.  An asynchronous call can not return stuff to the original caller, you need to use callback better a promise which once done with the async call you will get executed but by the original caller has completed its execution.

Comment: @neolivz4ever can you give me an example of that?

Answer (score 0):

before you explore the $http promises and async calls further, i think you may have to fix this:
from `var app_ctrl = angular.module('app.controllers');`
to this `var app_ctrl = angular.module('app.controllers', []);`

> [angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module): "The empty
>   array in angular.module('myApp', []). This array is the list of
>   modules myApp depends on."